# How to prevent "auto update with silent check" to start launcher on error?

Tags: install4j

We want to create an update application using the template for "Update with silent version check" to check the version before the launcher will be executed. So far everythings seems to work fine but when I get an error the update application will abort the process and rollback everything. After that the launcher will be executed. We need to abort the launcher execution if an error occured during the version check. Is it possible to configure this? The same goes for the scenario the user want to abort the update and click "exit" at the info dialog. The execution of the launcher should also be aborted. We tried it with version 5.1.15 and 6.0 with the same result that the launcher always is executed independend if an error occured or the user aborted the update.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "before the launcher will be executed" what launcher do you mean? The update template starts the downloaded installer but by default it does not start a launcher.

Comment: I meant the configuration to start one of the configured application launcher after the update process has finished. In the template there is the "Launcher Integration" tab with the option "Start automatically when the launcher is executed". That implied when I start the launcher the update application will be started first and blocks the launcher start until it has been finished. Maybe I have some missunderstandings there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more control over the behavior of the launcher after the updater has failed, don't use the automatic launcher integration. On the "Launcher integrations" tab there is an integration wizard that will give you a code snippet that you can insert into your main method.

`ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication` takes a `Callback` whose `exited` method is called with the exit value of the updater.

Comment: I suspected this would be the only possibility to handle the desired behavior yet. We want to prevent our application to have dependencies to any installer framework. Maybe this could be an enhancement to the install4j framework to set an activation flag at the template to ignore a start after errors or aborting the update? I would vote for it ;). For now I will see how to integrate the code snippet from the wizzard. Thank you so for.

Comment: Make a wrapper class in a separate module that calls your real main method. In that way you're application will still not depend on install4j.